# Android 13 Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT when device already connected to Bluetooth Headset

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-bluetooth

iam using Android 13 sdk 33.
My app is using bluetooth headset.
I got the SecurityException only when iam using Android 13 and i start the application while the device is already connected to the Headset.
When i start the application and after i connect the bluetooth Headset there is not Exception. So only when i start the app while its connecting. These permissions are
in the manifest file. I also tried it with **android:maxSdkVersion="30"** but its still not working.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
    android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
```

This is the build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 33
buildToolsVersion '30.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 44
    versionName "@string/app_version"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Here are my runtime permissions. I ask for them in the onCreate method of the LoginActivity.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH_33 = {
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
};


private static final String[] PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH = {
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
};

private String [] getBluetoothPermissions() {
    if(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
        return PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH_33;
    }
    return PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH;
}

private void checkPermissions(){
    
    int permission2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
                      Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
    int permission3 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
                      Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
    if (permission2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permission3 != 
               PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                getBluetoothPermissions(),
                1
        );
    }
}
```

This is only with Android 13. I did not try Android 12.
When i use a lower version of Android like Android 11 or Android 10 i can start my app while iam connected to Bluetooth headset.

The Exception i got is the following:

```
  Process: com.my.app, PID: 1907
java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for AttributionSource { uid = 10375, packageName = com.my.app, attributionTag = null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@1333f69, next = null }: HeadsetService
    at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.checkPermissionForDataDelivery(Utils.java:917)
    at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.checkConnectPermissionForDataDelivery(Utils.java:949)
    at com.android.bluetooth.hfp.HeadsetService$BluetoothHeadsetBinder.getService(HeadsetService.java:821)
    at com.android.bluetooth.hfp.HeadsetService$BluetoothHeadsetBinder.getConnectedDevicesWithAttribution(HeadsetService.java:908)
    at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothHeadset$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothHeadset.java:245)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1321)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1280)
```

This exception occurs ONLY when i start the app while my device is already connected to the Bluetooth Headset.
When i start the app with a lower version of android like 10, 11 its working fine.
It also works when i start the app and after the start i connect the bluetooth headset while using Android 13.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are checking for Bluetooth permissions at the right places in your code. It's good that you are checking permissions in the onCreate method of the LoginActivity. Also, instead of requesting all Bluetooth permissions at once, consider requesting them dynamically as needed. This allows you to figure out which permission is causing the issue. Finally, test your app on different Android versions, including Android 12, to see if the issue is specific to Android 13. This can help identify whether the problem is related to changes in Android 13 or if it's a broader compatibility issue.